# Mechanize Select First Form returns "ImportError: No module named html5lib"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, html5lib

After reading [this tutorial](http://stockrt.github.io/p/handling-html-forms-with-python-mechanize-and-BeautifulSoup/), I came up with this code,

```
import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import re
   import mechanize
   import cookielib
   
   # Browser
   br = mechanize.Browser()
   
  # Cookie Jar
  cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
  br.set_cookiejar(cj)
  
  # Browser options
  br.set_handle_equiv(True)
  br.set_handle_gzip(True)
  br.set_handle_redirect(True)
  br.set_handle_referer(True)
  br.set_handle_robots(False)
  
  # Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
  br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
  
  # User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
  br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
  
  # The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
  br.open('http://www.cleanmetrics.net/foodcarbonscope')
  
  br.select_form(nr=0)
  br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$userName'] = "XXXXX"
  br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$passWord'] = "XXXXXX"
  
  # Login
  br.submit()
```

Keeps getting this error:

```
File "scrapeRecipe.py", line 30, in <module>
    br.select_form(nr=0)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 619, in select_form
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/mechanize/_html.py", line 260, in global_form
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/mechanize/_html.py", line 267, in forms
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/mechanize/_html.py", line 282, in _get_forms
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/mechanize/_html.py", line 247, in root
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/mechanize/_html.py", line 145, in content_parser
ImportError: No module named html5lib
```

However, I know that I've successfully installed html5lib because when I run `pip3 freeze` I see

```
html5lib==0.999999999
six==1.10.0
webencodings==0.5.1
```

**Latest:**
I think my problem may have to do with my easy-install.pth file. In my site-packages directory, I don't actually see html5lib. I only have this:

```
BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg
appdirs-1.4.3.dist-info
appdirs.py
appdirs.pyc
beautifulsoup4-4.5.3.dist-info
bs4
easy-install.pth
html2text-2016.9.19-py2.7.egg
mechanize-0.3.1-py2.7.egg
packaging
packaging-16.8.dist-info
pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
requests-2.13.0-py2.7.egg
```

When I ran `easy_install html5lib`, I get `Adding html5lib 0.999999999 to easy-install.pth file`. However, after it successfully finished processing dependencies for html5lib, I opened my easy_install.pth file and I don't see html5lib mentioned anywhere?

```
   import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
   ./BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg
   ./html2text-2016.9.19-py2.7.egg
   ./mechanize-0.3.1-py2.7.egg
   ./requests-2.13.0-py2.7.egg
   ./pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
   import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+l    en(new)
```

Unless the html5lib is in one of those above packages? I'm wondering if I need to import html5lib in my python code and also list the root path?

don't really know why this is getting downvoted? :/

Comment: Have you tried ```pip install --ignore-installed six``` prior to these commands? And try running your command afterwards.

Comment: when I try to run your command, I get a "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six.py'"

Comment: Try running ```pip install --ignore-installed six --user```

Comment: also - do you have both python2 and 3 installed? one other possible error is that you are installing to the wrong interpreter. I assume ```pip3``` worked because you installed it for python3, but your default is python2.7 as shown. So you can try ```pip2``` as well, in case pip is screwed up somehow. The ```--user flag``` should work.

Comment: the --user flag worked, but still no dice when I ran my commands afterwards. I'm installing python 3.6.1 now

Comment: I tried to run my program on 3.6.1, but I get the same ImportError

Comment: There's a whole multitude of possible reasons mentioned in other questions around SO. Look through them and report on results.

Comment: In particular, the `build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/mechanize/` path looks strange.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev what exactly about the path is suspicious?

Comment: @Matt it's not a normal installation path. It rather looks like a directory for temporary build files.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev well the traceback is python itself looking for necessary modules when executing `import <module>`, correct? how does one reroute where the tracebook looks?

Answer (score -1):

I'm getting a different issue now, but this is the solution to the html5lib.

```
pip install --ignore-installed six --user
sudo -H pip install html5lib --ignore-installed
```

To learn more, this is an excellent thread:https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

Comment: You should never sudo on  PIP because it will mess up with your global packages. You might want to setup a virtual environment next time as well.